# Given a biased coin $P(X=0)=.75$, can someone show me a compression scheme that beats 1 bit

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

Given a biased coin $P(X=0)=.75$, I've been unable to find a coding scheme which beats the identity code of $0\to0$ and $1\to1$, which of course is an efficiency of 1 bit per transmission.

The entropy of the coin is $H(X)\approx.81$, and I'm aware that there's a 1 bit overhead for coding schemes restricted to a single transmission, but so long as the length $n$ of the transmission is sufficiently large, this should be possible.

I know virtually nothing about algebraic coding theory, so most of the codes I've tried have been basic, mostly just sending long strings of zeros to shorter codes using the Huffman coding scheme, but I haven't been able to get below 1 bit, I'm not even trying to get close to the Shannon limit, I'd just like to see a code which gets below 1 bit for $n$ sufficiently large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$n=2$ is sufficiently large. We then have
$$\begin{align} P(00) &= 9/16 \\ P(01) &= 3/16 \\ P(10) &= 3/16 \\ P(11) &= 1/16 \end{align} $$

And so we can construct a Huffman code:

```
00 coded as 0
10 coded as 10
01 coded as 110
11 coded as 111
```

The expected cost of sending two coin flips is now 
$$ 1 \cdot \frac9{16} + 2 \cdot \frac 3{16} + 3 \cdot \frac{3+1}{16} = \frac{27}{16} $$
so the expected cost *per coin flip* is $\frac{27/16}2 = \frac{27}{32} < 1 $.

Comment: wow so simple, I was sure bothering with '0' '1' combos would be a mistake since they are low probability but mapping them to the longer code lengths makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: @Tyroshipleasurebarge The point here is that you don't have to guess. The Huffman theorem comes with an algorithm that you can run to find the optimal code for certain probability distribution on the messages, and from the code you can calculate the entropy. In this case the probability distribution was given, so all you had to do was run the algorithm and see if the resulting entropy was low enough.